# Morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(K) \to \operatorname{Spec}(K[x]/(x^2))$ is not flat under any restriction to open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be the morphism of the affine schemes, where $X=\operatorname{Spec}(K)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(K[x]/(x^2)).$ Show that there isn't an open neighbourhood $U$ of generic point $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is flat.

Let $R=K[x]/(x^2).$ I have an impression that I'm missing something. Particularly, I don't understand from definition why this isn't flat morphism. Indeed, one has to check if $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(R),f(x)}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(K),x}$ is a flat ring map for every point of $\operatorname{Spec}(K),$ but $\operatorname{Spec}(K)$ has exactly one point, namely $(0),$ so one has to check only one map on stalks. We have $x=(0),$ so $f(x)=(0),$ so $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(R),f(x)}=K$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(K),x}=K.$ Ring map $K\rightarrow K$ is flat, so... where is my mistake...?
Similarly, if I get second neighbourhood of $(0),$ namely $(0),$ I'll again obtain morphism on stalks as $K\rightarrow K.$

I make something really wrong, but I'm missing it, I don't notice that. I would like to ask you for a help.

Comment: A formatting tip for the future: I've changed your \text{Spec} to \operatorname{Spec}, which handles spacing better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is the claim that $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(R),f(x)}=K$. This is not correct: instead, $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(R),f(x)}=K[x]/(x^2)$. Now all you have to do is demonstrate that $K[x]/(x^2)\to K$ is not flat, which should be straightforwards.

Comment: Ok, but when I get morphism $ f:f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U,$ where $U=0 ,$ I obtain homorphism $\mathcal{O}_{U, f(x)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(U),x}= \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(K),x}$ .Left−hand side shouldn′t be equal $K$? Why this restriction is not flat?

Comment: As I have said in the answer, the LHS of that equation is $K[x]/(x^2)$. This can be checked as follows: $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a one-point space, so the stalk at the unique point is just the global sections, which for $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is just $R=K[x]/(x^2)$. Do you think something else should be happening here?

Comment: Oh my god, I got also an ideal $(0)$ in $R$ as prime, which is not of course prime, because $R$ is not a domain. Unbelievable... Now everything is very obvious! Thanks!

Comment: As some small comfort, nobody is immune from mistakes like this. Glad to help you resolve your question.